# Empty spaces are generated in the bottom of page, after updating the datatable which is scrollable, in primefaces

Tags: css, jsf, primefaces

Scrollbar  appears, the page extends vertically, and generates empty spaces.  Layoutunit adjusst the height of page like "the height of datatable which is parametered scrollable="false"".

My layoutunit:

```
<p:layoutUnit id="mainCenterLayoutUnit" position="center" size="auto">
```

My datatable;

```
<p:dataTable id="xxx" var="tableRow"
    widgetVar="yyyy" value="#{bean.list}"
    rowKey="#{tableRow.oid}" selectionMode="single" scrollable="true"
    scrollHeight="300" emptyMessage="#{attrArt.table_empty_message}">  
</p:dataTable>
```

Before update:
[image]

After update:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LChoi.jpg]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding

```
.ui-datatable-scrollable table{
    position: relative;
}
```

to you css file. This will help with extra space under your page, but will cause empty space appearance inside of datatable scroll panel.